# Reload data for UIView\UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, reloaddata

When I am moving the buttons on the screen from a function, [self makeButtons], nothing happends unless I push a viewcontroller, then pop back. Is there a reload data function for ViewController, as it is for UITableViews? I am using NavigationController, and I am adding subviews to a UISrollView and moving other buttons on the screen. The method is called after fetching data with ASIFORMHTTPRequest.

EDIT: I am sorry I didn't specify more.

I have a method that is sending a [request startAsynchronous] (ASIFORMHTTPrequest).
I have a NSMutableArray containing all my buttons. When the request is done, a method called doneGettingRequest, which looks like this.

```
- (void) doneGettingRequest(ASIFORMHTTPRequest *) request {
    [self removeButtons];
}
```

which is calling this method;

```
- (void) removeButtons {
    NSLog(@"Removing buttons!");
    for (UIButton *button in gameButtons) {
        [button removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Everything works when I go to another view, then back again. The problem is it won't refresh if THAT view is being shown when the method is called (which will happend almost always). The gameButton is a NSMutableArray containing buttons that are currently being showed. When I am done removing them, I want to add some other buttons. The problem is, the buttons is not removed when the removeButtons is called. The message "Removing buttons!" however, is shown, so the method is being called.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry if I am doing something wrong... I am totally new to this.

Comment: Can you show your code? It would help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your logic in your **viewWillAppear**.

This method is called before the receiver’s view is about to be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured for showing the view.

You can override this method to perform custom tasks associated with displaying the view.

If you override this method, you **must** call super at some point in your implementation.

Comment: All the methods are being called in one view, which is also the present view. Would viewWillAppear get the view to update/refresh?

Comment: Yes, i guess. Did you try that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 [view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, it didn't refresh my view. Nothing changes until I go to another view and then pop back... Thanks anyway

Comment: Are you using nib file or creating dynamically.

Comment: The buttons is added programatically, I am using NavigationController and IB storyboard.